# d3 Cannot read property 'classed' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

Trying to highlight current path line by grabbing **pathID** of a current path and assigning it a **class .highlight** that makes `stroke-width: 2px`.

console.log shows **current pathID** but it doesn't want to assign a class. Please help. What am I doing wrong here?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/edgarkiljak/pen/JeXXdV)

```
//Generate group (main)
    let groups = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .call(revealCityName)
        })
        .on("mouseout", hideCityName)

//Path (path #, path line)
groups
    .append("path").classed("line", true)
    .attr("id", function(d) {
        console.log(d.country)
        if (d && d.length != 0) {
            return d.country.replace(/ |,|\./g, '_');
        }
    })
    .attr("d", d => line(d.emissions))
    .classed("unfocused", true)
    .style("stroke-width", d =>
        d.country === "China" ? 1 : 0.2
    )
    .on("mouseover", highlightPath);

//Text (contries on the left y axis)
groups
    .append("text")
    .datum(function(d) {
        return { country: d.country, value: d.emissions[d.emissions.length - 1]};
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        if (d.value) {
            return "translate(" + xScale(d.value.year) + "," + yScale(d.value.amount) + ")";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    })
    .attr("x", 3)
    .attr("dy", 4)
    .style("font-size", 10)
    .style("font-family", "Abril Fatface")
    .text(d => d.country)
    .classed("hidden", function(d) {
        if (d.value && d.value.amount > 700000) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    })
```

And a function where I'm trying to assign a class:

```
    function highlightPath(d) {

    let pathID = d3.select(this).attr("id");

    console.log(pathID);

    let currentId = d3.select(this).select("path#" + pathID)
    console.log("Current ID: ",currentId)
    .classed("highlight", true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` is splitting code. Here is the error:

```
function highlightPath(d) {

    let pathID = d3.select(this).attr("id");

    console.log(pathID);

    let currentId = d3.select(this).select("path#" + pathID)
    console.log("Current ID: ",currentId) /* <<<<<<<<< HERE (line 218 in your codepen) */ 
    .classed("highlight", true);
}
```

Should be:

```
function highlightPath(d) {

    let pathID = d3.select(this).attr("id");

    console.log(pathID);

    let currentId = d3.select(this).classed('highlight', true) // thanks to @shashank

    console.log("Current ID: ", currentId)
}
```

Updated demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQRJXp

UPDATED after @Shashank comment

> `highlightPath` is a `mouseover` event bound to the path which results in
>   `d3.select(this)` to be the path itself and so you won't need any
>   `.select(path#pathID)` in this case but just
>   `d3.select(this).classed('highlighted', true)`

Comment: Good catch but updated codepen still isn't properly applying highlight class.

Comment: This question title is **d3 Cannot read property 'classed' of undefined** - I answered on this. Please avoid asking multiple questions in one article.

Comment: @EdgarKiljak This ***is*** the correct answer to your question. If you comment out the `console.log()` or move the line as suggested by @qiAlex's answer the codepen works just fine.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt but I see that it doesn't work and here's why: `highlightPath` is a mouseover event bound to the `path` which results in `d3.select(this)` to be the `path` itself and so you won't need any `.select(path#pathID)` in this case but just `d3.select(this).classed('highlighted', true)` should work.

Comment: @Shashank, Thank you that pointed, I updated an answer. Only guess that not `classed('highlighted', true)` but `classed('highlight', true)`

Comment: @Shashank Thank you but it does not highlighting a path

Comment: @EdgarKiljak Again, this is a different question. It's about the [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity) of CSS selectors. In your case the class `highlight` is in fact set on the path. You won't see any change, though, because it is trumped by the more specific `path.line` selector and the `style` attribute on the element itself.

Comment: @altocumulus Thank you! Finally solved it just with `d3.select(this).style("stroke-width", 3)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function highlightPath(d) {

    let pathID = d3.select(this).attr("id");

    console.log(pathID);

    d3.select("path#" + pathID)
    .attr("class", "highlight");
}
```